# Cannot read the property of undefined map

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, api

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, Text } from "react-native-paper";
import {
  SafeAreaView,
} from "react-native";

class Hnews extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isLoaded: false,
    };
  }

  // Function to collect data
  async componentDidMount() {
    await fetch(
      "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/26061935.json?print=pretty"
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          data: json.data,
          
        });
        console.log("Json", JSON.stringify(json));
      });
  }

    
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
          <Card>
        {this.state.newdata.map((item) => {
         <Text>{item.title}</Text>
  })}
  </Card>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

export default Hnews;
```

I am doing a hacker news clone, I am fetching the API and showing it but gives the error "Cannot read the property of undefined(reading 'map')". I have seen many answers to this type of question and had changed my solution but nothing works.

Comment: when do you call someMethod ?

Comment: I did console.log and it was giving me nothing. I removed it. Updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i can see from `this.state.newdata.map((item)` you are trying to map , `this.state.newdata` and if you pay attention you are storing data to `newdata` state by calling `someMethod` which you never called within your app , so always the `newdata` state will be empty, the following should fix it for you:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, Text } from "react-native-paper";
import {
  SafeAreaView,
} from "react-native";

class Hnews extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isLoaded: false,
    };
  }

  // Function to collect data
  async componentDidMount() {
    await fetch(
      "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/26061935.json?print=pretty"
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          data: json.data,
          
        });
        console.log("Json", JSON.stringify(json));
      });
  }

    
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
          <Card>
        {this.state.data.map((item) => {
         <Text>{item.title}</Text>
  })}
  </Card>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

export default Hnews;
```

and if you pay attention to data you are fetching you will understand that there is no mapable item there , you can only map on `kids`

[image]

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: updated the answer @Gaurav

Answer (score -1):

Your code snippet seems incomplete. However, your function someMethod is probably the culprit if it is being invoked in your code anywhere.

In it, you set the state’s newdata field to be a string by assigning it the JSON.stringify output. Once it is a string, there is no map function to call on it, which I’m assuming is why you’re getting the undefined error. It needs to be an array of items to use map function.

If you remove newdata altogether and only reference data, it should work, assuming response data is an array.

Comment: updated the code some time ago